# How to know right headers for API request?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to hit this POST API from last 2 hours, but I'm stuck with this error.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    /*POST API*/
    @Headers(HEADER)
    @POST("Api/signup")
    Call<String> addSignUpData(@Body SignUp signUp);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `SignUp` class

Comment: @Christilyn Can you please test API here? https://resttesttest.com/

Comment: @Christilyn when I add parameter it says: "The User name field is required.\nThe email field is required.\nThe Password field is
required.\n"}

Answer (score 0):

Set your Base url to:

```
     public static final String BASE_URL = 
    "http://clarigoinfotech.co.in/";
```

Comment: when I add parameter it says: "The User name field is required.\nThe email field is required.\nThe Password field is
required.\n"}

Answer (score 0):

GSon can't parse your json from your objects, Please change your response to json object

or create an entity class for your response

```
Call<JsonObject> addSignUpData(@Body SignUp signUp)
```

or

```
Call<SignupResult> addSignUpData(@Body SignUp signUp)


public SignupResult{

   boolean response ;

   String message;

   ...
}
```

your header must be in this format

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
```

and add `GsonConverterFactory` to your retrofit service :

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
     .build
```

Comment: when I add parameter it says: "The User name field is required.\nThe email field is required.\nThe Password field is
required.\n"}

Comment: Your retrofit has a response and it seems that your body parameters are different from your server implementation. please check your server-side parameters

Comment: This is someone else API and I've to test it without asking them!